# Why can't an index cover a query that includes an $or expression?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I was doing a couple of "covered query" tests in MongoDB 3.2 and noticed that it doesn't cover a query that includes an `$or` expression (only on the same field?). However, if I substitute the `$or` expression for an `$in` expression in the same query, it works just fine.

The index I used for testing was the following:

```
db.test_collection.createIndex({ a: 1, b: 1, c: 1 });
```

This is the `$or` query that **isn't** covered by the index

```
db.test_collection.find({
    a: "string",
    $or: [
        { b: true },
        { b: false },
    ],
    c: "string"
}, { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, _id: 0 });
```

and this is the `$in` query that **is** covered

```
db.test_collection.find({
    a: "string",
    b: { $in: [ true, false ] },
    c: "string"
}, { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, _id: 0 });
```

The fields are the same, the projections are the same. So, why can't the index cover the `$or` query?

---

This is the `explain()` output for the `$or` query:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.test_collection",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "$or" : [
                                                {
                                                        "b" : {
                                                                "$eq" : true
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "b" : {
                                                                "$eq" : false
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                {
                                        "a" : {
                                                "$eq" : "string"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "c" : {
                                                "$eq" : "string"
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "transformBy" : {
                                "a" : 1,
                                "b" : 1,
                                "c" : 1,
                                "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "$or" : [
                                                {
                                                        "b" : {
                                                                "$eq" : true
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "b" : {
                                                                "$eq" : false
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "a" : 1,
                                                "b" : 1,
                                                "c" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "a_1_b_1_c_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "a" : [
                                                        "[\"string\", \"string\"]"
                                                ],
                                                "b" : [
                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                ],
                                                "c" : [
                                                        "[\"string\", \"string\"]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 2,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 9,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 2,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 2,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "nReturned" : 2,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                        "works" : 3,
                        "advanced" : 2,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "transformBy" : {
                                "a" : 1,
                                "b" : 1,
                                "c" : 1,
                                "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "$or" : [
                                                {
                                                        "b" : {
                                                                "$eq" : true
                                                        }
                                                },
                                                {
                                                        "b" : {
                                                                "$eq" : false
                                                        }
                                                }
                                        ]
                                },
                                "nReturned" : 2,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                                "works" : 3,
                                "advanced" : 2,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 0,
                                "restoreState" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "docsExamined" : 2,
                                "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "nReturned" : 2,
                                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 10,
                                        "works" : 3,
                                        "advanced" : 2,
                                        "needTime" : 0,
                                        "needYield" : 0,
                                        "saveState" : 0,
                                        "restoreState" : 0,
                                        "isEOF" : 1,
                                        "invalidates" : 0,
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "a" : 1,
                                                "b" : 1,
                                                "c" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "a_1_b_1_c_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : false,
                                        "isUnique" : false,
                                        "isSparse" : false,
                                        "isPartial" : false,
                                        "indexVersion" : 1,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "a" : [
                                                        "[\"string\", \"string\"]"
                                                ],
                                                "b" : [
                                                        "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
                                                ],
                                                "c" : [
                                                        "[\"string\", \"string\"]"
                                                ]
                                        },
                                        "keysExamined" : 2,
                                        "dupsTested" : 0,
                                        "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                        "seenInvalidated" : 0
                                }
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "VM-TOMLIN-HP",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.2.6",
                "gitVersion" : "05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

and this is the `explain()` output for the `$in` query:

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.test_collection",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "a" : {
                                                "$eq" : "string"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "c" : {
                                                "$eq" : "string"
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "b" : {
                                                "$in" : [
                                                        false,
                                                        true
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "transformBy" : {
                                "a" : 1,
                                "b" : 1,
                                "c" : 1,
                                "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "a" : 1,
                                        "b" : 1,
                                        "c" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "a_1_b_1_c_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "a" : [
                                                "[\"string\", \"string\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "b" : [
                                                "[false, false]",
                                                "[true, true]"
                                        ],
                                        "c" : [
                                                "[\"string\", \"string\"]"
                                        ]
                                }
                        }
                },
                "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
        },
        "executionStats" : {
                "executionSuccess" : true,
                "nReturned" : 2,
                "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
                "totalKeysExamined" : 2,
                "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
                "executionStages" : {
                        "stage" : "PROJECTION",
                        "nReturned" : 2,
                        "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                        "works" : 3,
                        "advanced" : 2,
                        "needTime" : 0,
                        "needYield" : 0,
                        "saveState" : 0,
                        "restoreState" : 0,
                        "isEOF" : 1,
                        "invalidates" : 0,
                        "transformBy" : {
                                "a" : 1,
                                "b" : 1,
                                "c" : 1,
                                "_id" : 0
                        },
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                "nReturned" : 2,
                                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                                "works" : 3,
                                "advanced" : 2,
                                "needTime" : 0,
                                "needYield" : 0,
                                "saveState" : 0,
                                "restoreState" : 0,
                                "isEOF" : 1,
                                "invalidates" : 0,
                                "keyPattern" : {
                                        "a" : 1,
                                        "b" : 1,
                                        "c" : 1
                                },
                                "indexName" : "a_1_b_1_c_1",
                                "isMultiKey" : false,
                                "isUnique" : false,
                                "isSparse" : false,
                                "isPartial" : false,
                                "indexVersion" : 1,
                                "direction" : "forward",
                                "indexBounds" : {
                                        "a" : [
                                                "[\"string\", \"string\"]"
                                        ],
                                        "b" : [
                                                "[false, false]",
                                                "[true, true]"
                                        ],
                                        "c" : [
                                                "[\"string\", \"string\"]"
                                        ]
                                },
                                "keysExamined" : 2,
                                "dupsTested" : 0,
                                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                                "seenInvalidated" : 0
                        }
                }
        },
        "serverInfo" : {
                "host" : "VM-TOMLIN-HP",
                "port" : 27017,
                "version" : "3.2.6",
                "gitVersion" : "05552b562c7a0b3143a729aaa0838e558dc49b25"
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: What MongoDB version are you using? Also, could you post the `explain()` results of both queries?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha I'm using 3.2.6. Added this, as well as the `explain()` outputs to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way the **$or** operator is processed. According to the [video](https://youtu.be/IE2d5DBjNsQ?t=2m57s) from the official MongoDB course:

> The $or operator takes an array and the array contains documents, each
>   document is treated as a separate query and the $or operator matches
>   any document that matches any of those queries inside the array and so
>   it in effect computes the union of these queries.

Further, as the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-clauses-and-indexes) states:

> for MongoDB to use indexes to evaluate an **$or** expression, all the
>   clauses in the **$or** expression must be supported by indexes.
>   Otherwise, MongoDB will perform a collection scan.

The given index would be used if you rewrote the query to something like this:

```
db.test_collection.find({
    $or: [
        { a: "string", b: true, c: "string"},
        { a: "string", b: false, c: "string" },
    ],
}, { a: 1, b: 1, c: 1, _id: 0 });
```

Moreover, the documentation directly [recommends](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#or-versus-in) to use the **$in** operator to check equality of the same field.

Comment: Sure, it recommends `$in`, and your example does work, but I don't get what the difference is. Especially between your `$or` query and mine. To me those are exactly the same queries. I'd like to know why it doesn't work (since this isn't described in the documentation), and not just that it doesn't. I already know that from testing :)

Comment: As far as I understand the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IE2d5DBjNsQ) from the official mongodb course, the difference is in the purpose of the commands. Each expression in the **$or** operator is treated as a separate query and the union of their results is returned as opposed to **$in** which just matches a field in a documents against a set of values.

Comment: That last minute of the video actually cleared things up. They should really mention that in the documentation :/ Thanks for finding it, and linking it. If you can rewrite your answer to include this information I'll be happy to mark it as "accepted" :)